# Create a parallel 'for' loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, joblib

I have some code that loops through a dictionary where the key is a word and it assigns the term frequency to that key. `tok` is a list of tokens from some text.

```
def calculateTF(wordDict, tok):
    tfDict = {}
    termCount = len(tok)
    for word, count in wordDict.iteritems():
        tfDict[word] = count / float(termCount)
    return tfDict
```

I want to split up the task of iterating over the wordDict where `tfDict[word] = count / float(termCount)` is executed

Comment: and by parallel you mean: multi-processing?

Comment: To get an answer more quickly and of higher quality it's important to explain the problem in detail. You write _"I can't get joblib to loop through the for loop",_ but  `joblib` is nowhere in the code you've provided. So we cannot identify what it is you're doing wrong, if you don't show us what you have tried. Also, what does it mean that you can't get it to work? Does it provide wrong result (in that case; what results?) or is it creating errors (in that case; what errors?). Or is your question about how `joblib` works?

Comment: It's unclear how your question relates to `joblib`. Also, what you're doing in the `for` loop will likely **not** benefit from either of Python's built-in parallel-processing libraries, `multiprocessing` and `threading`, since it's compute-bound and is updating a global (`tfDict`).

Comment: Sorry, I tried to implement joblib previously but I didn't know how to use it. Or if it even is what I need for this. I've only used to openMP in C and this is all brand new.

I'm trying to execute it so it will split up the iteration of wordDict

Answer (score 1):

The [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) module in Python is both Unix and Windows compatible and offers remote and local concurrency.  The [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) uses subprocesses instead of threads.  Processes are spawned by creating a ‘Process’ object and then calling its [start()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.start) method.  The process follows the API of [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

The below example demonstrates how to execute two different functions, each with a for loop, in parallel by creating a process for each.  As an interesting note, each process its own address space (virtual memory). So, program variables are not shared between processes.  To illustrate this, I’ve created two global variables and set them to the opposite value that they should take when updated by the local variables.  As you can see, they stay opposite and don’t update.  You can use IPC, interprocess communication, techniques to share data between two processes.

**Code**

```
import multiprocessing

global_any = False
global_all = True

def calculate_any(number):
    local_list_any = [1,2,3]
    local_result_any = any(True if i == number else False for i in local_list_any)
    global_any = local_result_any
    print("This is the first result within a process: {}".format(local_result_any))

def calculate_all(number):
    local_list_all = [1,2,3]
    local_result_all = all(True if i == number else False for i in local_list_all)
    global_all = local_result_all
    print("This is the second result within a process: {}".format(local_result_all))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = 2
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = calculate_any, args = (number,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = calculate_all, args = (number,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print('The result of the ANY global variable: {}'.format(global_any))
    print('The result of the ALL global variable: {}'.format(global_all))
```

**Result**

```
The result of the ANY global variable: False
The result of the ALL global variable: True
This is the first result within a process: True
This is the second result within a process: False
```

**References**

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lu5LrKh1Zno

Comment: How does this illustrate making a parallel `for` loop?

Comment: @martineau hey martineau, I updated my answer to provide a better explanation.

Comment: Your changes are an improvement—at least the two separate functions now both contain a `for` loop. Each of them is still very different from the `for` loop in the OP's question and are not updating anything shared between the main process and subprocesses—so it's unclear (to me) how much help your answer is going to be to them. To be fair, the question itself is very vague about exactly what they want to accomplish.